In what way is every function in $\aleph_0$ given by a family of coprojections?
I'm reading the paper The Category Theoretic Understanding of Universal Algebra: Lawvere Theories and Monads by Martin Hyland and John Power, and there's this bit I don't understand (emphasis mine):

The requirement that $M$ preserves projections, which is part of what
preservation of products means, determines the behaviour of $M$ on the
basic product operation $If$ for every function $f$: for projections
in $L$ amount to coprojections in $\aleph_0$, and every function $f$
there is given by a family of coprojections. So what determines a
model is the interpretation of the other operations.

In what way is every function in $\aleph_0$, the category of finite sets and their functions, given by a family of coprojections?

Consider the finite set F:= $ \{ 1,2,3 \} $. Any function f from $\{ 1,2,3 \}$ is determined by its value on the singletons sets whose disjoint union is F. Say for example that $f(1) = a, f(2) = b, f(3) = c$. Now view f as the disjoint union of functions $f_i: \{i\} \rightarrow \{a,b,c\}$, where for example $f_1(1) = a$. The $f_i$ are the coprojections here* since they satisfy the appropriate universal property for F the disjoint sum (that is, they uniquely determine f).
Now generalize this to any finite set.
*this terminology is somewhat loose, some people call $p_i:\{i\} \rightarrow F$ defined by $p_i(i) = i$ the coprojections. Then $f \circ p_i$ gives us our $f_i$.

That was what I thought too, however in that case $f$ is determined by the $f_i$s, not by the coprojections proper. Putting this in the context of the paragraph, why couldn't two functors $F,G: \aleph_0 \to C$ that preserve coproducts map $f$ to different morphisms $Ff \neq Gf$?

Consider the trivial Lawvere category $\aleph_0^{op}$. Models M,N into Set for this category are determined by where they send 1. In particular, they can send 1 to different objects, hence map the same morphism in $\aleph_0^{op}$ to different morphisms. (This is all discussed later in the same paper).

But this isn't the point of the paragraph. Rather, the idea is that, say for $L_{mon}$, we can have two set valued functors corresponding to two different monoids, each of these monoids behaves in the expected manner on basic product operations, but these actual operation of a monoid is what determines the model itself.  I think Milewski has a nice write up on this

In Hylands words: " Mod(L, Set) is equivalent to the evident category of such structures", ie Mon is equivalent to $Mod (L_{mon}, Set)$

Ooh I see, you have to choose $F1$ and also $Ff$ for every $f : 1 \to m$. So much for being determined by the property of preserving coprojections! Thank you :)
